# What is the difference between SELECT_BY_POS and SELECT_BY_TICKET in Mql4 language

Tags: mql4

In my Mql4 expert advisor code, I want to select some orders which have been placed and currently active. I can use both of these ways and I have different results with them. `OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS)` or `OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_TICKET)`. What are the possible reasons for these differences?

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT_BY_TICKET` allows you to pick up a particular ticket if you know its id and this ticket is still open. Example: your ea opened a ticket with `int _ticket=OrderSend(***);` this `_ticket` can be kept in memory of the ea and then checked each tick or bar or what you want, if the ticket is still open, if not - then you can check if it was closed with a loss or profit and react on that(increase lot if loss if you are doing martingale).

`SELECT_BY_POS` allows you to select a ticket out of number of open tickets obtained from `OrdersTotal()`. It also allows to get all tickets that are closed if you use `OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)`, and then you can do manipulations with that selected ticket (e.g., you can check its id, magic number of symbol, type to filter required tickets and check how they were closed).